# Meaning of this.__canvases.push(canvas);

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

While checking fabric js example at http://fabricjs.com/customization/
I could se  **this.__canvases.push(canvas);** being called, I just could not figure out why it is called and what if do not call it.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c2');
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
canvas.selection = false;
this.__canvases.push(canvas);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the HTML of the example page you will find the following code on lines 95-98

```
<script>
  this.__canvases = [ ];
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';
</script>
```

This generates an empty array, which gets populated when you use `this.__canvases.push(canvas);` by appending the canvas object onto the end of the array (See [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push))

This array is then used by the following code (found on lines 455-468)

```
(function() {
  fabric.util.addListener(fabric.window, 'load', function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas || this.canvas,
        canvases = this.__canvases || this.canvases;

    canvas && canvas.calcOffset && canvas.calcOffset();

    if (canvases && canvases.length) {
      for (var i = 0, len = canvases.length; i < len; i++) {
        canvases[i].calcOffset();
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

This code merely just calculates the position to display the canvas elements on the example page.

So to answer your question, it is only used on the example page to help display the example page. You do not need it in your code. In my opinion it should not have been included on the code display for each example.